# Unable to migrate Newtonsoft to System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json.net, system.text.json, .net-7.0

I have the following method that takes in a string of JSON and adds a new property to it

```
private string AddRequesterToJson(string initialJson, string requestedBy)
{
    var json = JObject.Parse(initialJson);
    json.Add("requestedBy", requestedBy);
    return json.ToString();
}
```

This works fine and adds the new property to the JSON but now I'm trying to remove Newtonsoft from the project but I'm having problems as as I can't seem to do a `.add` after I convert the string to an object:

```
private string AddRequesterToJson(string initialJson, string requestedBy)
{
    var json = JsonObject.Parse(initialJson);

    if (json != null)
    {
        json.Add("requestedBy", requestedBy); // parse seems to create a json node instead of a json object so there is no add here

        return json.ToJsonString();
    }

    return initialJson;
}
```

I have also tried using `JsonDocument.Parse` but that also doesn't let me add a new property to it.  Is there a way of adding a new property to the JSON string before outputting it again using `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.json.jsonobject.setnamedvalue?view=winrt-22621#windows-data-json-jsonobject-setnamedvalue(system-string-windows-data-json-ijsonvalue) is what you're likely after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
//using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

private string AddRequesterToJson(string initialJson, string requestedBy)
{
    var json = JsonNode.Parse(initialJson);
    json.AsObject().Add("requestedBy", requestedBy);
    return json.ToString();
}
```

The "AsObject().Add" method will add a new element/node to the json object at the root level.